# JSON_ENCONDE -> getJSON Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to retrieve the array but nothing happes even the $('#grupos tbody tr').empty(); works outside the .getJSON but not inside!!! help im crazy!!!
Can someone outthere help me out with this!!!

PHP

```
<?php
include_once('../config/db.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM grupos";
$result = mysqli_query(conn(),$query);
$res = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        array_push($res, array(

            'g_id'          =>          $row[0],
            's_id'          =>          $row[1],
            'termino'       =>          $row[2],
            'fecha'         =>          $row[3]

            ));

    echo json_encode(array('result' => $res));
    }
?>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/clinicaclasses/grupos.php', function(data){
        $('#grupos tbody tr').empty();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because output of your php file is not a valid JSON.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    array_push($res, array(

        'g_id'          =>          $row[0],
        's_id'          =>          $row[1],
        'termino'       =>          $row[2],
        'fecha'         =>          $row[3]

        ));

echo json_encode(array('result' => $res));
}
```

Here you `echo` JSON-string on every iteration. And you shoud echo it **after** `while` loop is over.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    array_push($res, array(

        'g_id'          =>          $row[0],
        's_id'          =>          $row[1],
        'termino'       =>          $row[2],
        'fecha'         =>          $row[3]

        ));
}
echo json_encode(array('result' => $res));
```

Comment: THNX man I really need some rest of this project! but THNK YOU SO FRREAKING MUCH!!

Comment: Now it works but  when alerting the data.result says undifined!!??!!??